# sending form data through Jquery and AJAX is not working as expected

Tags: ajax, post

I have a form containing two submit buttons, i want it to update the current page as soon as i submit the form without refreshing the whole page, but the code keeps reloading the page and the page is not even updated.

HTML form

```
 <form id="paymentForm" style="margin-left: 15%;margin-bottom: 15px;margin-top:15px;font-size: 18px;" action="#">
  <input class="paymentButton" type="submit" name="COD" value="Cash on Delivery(COD)" style="background-color:#F80;color:white;height: 60px;border-radius: 5px ">
  <input class="paymentButton" type="submit" name="POD" value="Paytm on Delivery(POD)" style="margin-left: 25px;background-color: #F80;color:white;height: 60px;border-radius: 5px">
```

Jquery and AJAX code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#paymentForm").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var buttonpressed;
      var paymentValue;
      $("#paymentbutton").click(function() {
      paymentValue = $(this).attr('value') ;

      });
      $.ajax({ 
         url:"payment.php",
         type:'POST',
         data:"{ 
              buttonValue:paymentValue; 
         }",
         success:function(data){
             getElementById('panel13').innerHTML=data;
         }  
        });
           return false;
      });

    });
```

PHP script payment.php where data is being sent

```
<?php
 $paymentMode="" 
 if(isset($_POST["buttonValue"]==POD))
    $paymentMode="Paytm On Delivery";
 else
    $paymentMode="Cash on Delivery";
echo "Your Order is placed succesfully with payment mode as" .$paymentMode;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]You have an syntax error in php code

```
$paymentMode="";
```

Youre mising `semicolon`... Next time, each time you send an ajax request. Turn on `chrome dev tool -> network -> XHR` to see what really haapen with your request. If request has failse. Click on request(i have red color) to see. back end error.. Hope this helpfull...

Comment: I placed the semicolon there, but still it isn't working .

Comment: @prakharpandey Check you network at the time you send ajax request like the picture above... To see what really wrong with your request ?

Comment: Thanks for help ! I noticed later that i had another syntax error. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getElementById`, use `document.getElementById` instead. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for help !! It's working fine after the changes suggested in all the answers.